# What Shabbat malachot are allowed on Rosh Hashanah(Sunday)?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year

I was wondering what Shabbat malachot are allowed on Rosh Hashanah(Sunday). I know that I am allowed to carry, transfer a flame, and increase a flame. Are there any other ones? I am specifically wondering if I am allowed to write. Thank you.

Comment: It's like any other Yom Tov where only food preparation related activities would be permissible. Writing isn't included

Comment: Ein Bein Shabbos VYomtov ELA Ochel Nefesh (B'Yomtov)